# Spring Cloud Config server - Logback error

Tags: java, spring, logback, spring-cloud

I am creating a client. I use a remote server. The bootstrap file is:

```
spring.application.name=myApp
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.cloud.config.uri=https://url.config.server
spring.cloud.config.username=user
spring.cloud.config.password=pass
logging.config=${spring.cloud.config.uri}/${spring.application.name}/${spring.profiles.active}/master/logback-spring.xml
```

The problem is when it tries to read the logbook-spring.xml. The server return the http code 401.

It is not using the username and password.

Does anyone have any idea how the log file could read?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you ever fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here we can find more information about it: 
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/721